# what does the code mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

pleas help me understand that's the meaning of following code. the functions after the route are executed continuously one by one, or depending on the http request type, only execute one at a time? Thanks

```
app.route('/api/articles/:articleId')
   .get(articles.read)
   .put(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.update)
   .delete(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.delete);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "continuously"? All three functions will be executed, one at a time, in the order they appear.

Answer (score 0):

What is not clear here?

You call an API endpoint (route).
For `get()` request you don't need authorisation, whilst for `put()` and `delete()` you need.

You have 3 chained methods, instead calling each one separately.

And it won't call all 3 methods at once, but rather call the right one based on request sent to the endpoint. You can have one request, and based on that it will iterate through a method calls, and see the method that corresponds to a request.
If the request type doesn't exist it will discard it and present you with error.

That means if you want to fetch data `get()` will hapilly return data if it exists, and for other two will ask you to **Log in(authorize)** the changes.

Hopefully this answers your question.